# $r^{th}$ moment and moment generating function of a (normally distributed) random variable

Tags: statistics

I am given 3 things:

1. $Z$ follows a normal distribution $N(0,1)$
2. $Y=e^{X}$
3. $X=3-2Z$

What is the moment generation function of $X$ and the $r^{th}$ moment of $Y$ ($E[Y^{r}]$).

My attempt:

I know that $M_{X}(t)=E[e^{tX}]=E[e^{t(\mu+\sigma Z)}]=e^{\mu t + (\sigma ^2 t^2)/2}$. So by $X=3-2Z$, $3$ is $\mu$ and $-2$ is $\sigma$?

I am lost on where to begin for finding, $r^{th}$ moment of $Y$.

Comment: $E(Y^r)=E(e^{rX})=M_X(r)$.

Comment: For finding the parameters of X, Consider $E[X] = E[3-2Z]$ and $Var[X] = Var[3-2Z] = (-2)^2Var[Z] = 4Var[Z]$, so $Var[X]= 4$

Comment: @Pablo, but just looking at how moment generating function of X is expressed, can't I automatically find that $\mu$ is $3$ and $\sigma$ is $-2$?

Comment: @i707107, If $Z$ is $N(0,1)$, that doesn't necessarily have any bearing on the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of $X$, right? Is my attempt correct?

Comment: @ozarka You can, I just wanted to give another way to do so.  Also, as a semantic point, $\sigma$ is a measure of dispersion of the data, so it only takes positive values, so it should be 2